# StaleElementReferenceException error after button press with selenium + python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project using selenium. In this project, I am trying to scrape the links of products from multiple pages in amazon. For example, when I type **laptop** in the search bar in Amazon, multiple products are populated, and there exist multiple pages. I want to scrape all the product links from all pages and store them in a list.

This is my code so far

```
def scrape_pages_selenium(product, total_pages):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

    url = f'https://www.amazon.com/s?k={product}&page=1&ref=nb_sb_noss'

    driver.get(url)
    links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-size-mini")

    product_links = []
    for page in range(1, total_pages+1):

        for link in links:
            product_links.append(link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href'))

        print(len(product_links))

        try:
            next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-last")
            next_page_button.click()
        except:
            continue

    return product_links

product_links = scrape_pages_selenium('laptop', 7)
```

This code works correctly on the first page. The `next_page_button` is used to go to the next page. But when the code tries to scrape the links from the second page, I get the following error

```
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-09cc65b63734> in <module>
     23     return product_links
     24 
---> 25 product_links = scrape_pages_selenium('gatorade', 7)
     26 

<ipython-input-50-09cc65b63734> in scrape_pages_selenium(product, total_pages)
     12 
     13         for link in links:
---> 14             product_links.append(link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href'))
     15 
     16         print(len(product_links))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in find_element_by_css_selector(self, css_selector)
    428             element = element.find_element_by_css_selector('#foo')
    429         """
--> 430         return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
    431 
    432     def find_elements_by_css_selector(self, css_selector):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    657 
    658         return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT,
--> 659                              {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
    660 
    661     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("a-size-mini")` inside your loop. This is because when you move to the next page, the `links` collection is no more valid

`find_elements_by_class_name` is giving you a snapshot of what exists and the current page, when you move to the next page, that snapshot of dom elements is no more valid